# Spy service never being called in unit test (jasmine angular)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, testbed

I'm trying to understand why my test doesn't work as expected. Here is the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [HomeService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'testing-angular';

  constructor (private service: HomeService ) {}

  CallHomeService(): void {
    this.service.DoStuff();
  }
}
```

and here the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

  constructor() { }

  DoStuff(): void {
    console.log('homeService has been called')
  }

}
```

I'd like only to check if `DoStuff` has been called, so I did this test:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let appComponent: AppComponent;
  let homeServiceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<HomeService>; // Use jasmine.SpyObj type for mock

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Create a spy object for HomeService
    homeServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('HomeService', ['DoStuff']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [{provide: HomeService, useValue: homeServiceMock}] // Provide the spy object directly
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    appComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should call DoStuff() when CallHomeService() is called', () => {
    // Call the CallHomeService() method of AppComponent
    appComponent.CallHomeService();

    // Expect that DoStuff() was called on the mock HomeService
    expect(homeServiceMock.DoStuff).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Use toHaveBeenCalled() matcher
  });
});
```

But I get

```
AppComponent should call DoStuff() when CallHomeService() is called FAILED
        Expected spy HomeService.DoStuff to have been called.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.apply (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:28:37)
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:375:26)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:39)
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:374:52)
```

So I tried using the TestBed.overrideProvider and it worked:

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeService } from './service/home.service';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let appComponent: AppComponent;
  let homeService: jasmine.SpyObj<HomeService>; // Use jasmine.SpyObj type for mock

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Create a mock object for HomeService
    const homeServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('HomeService', ['DoStuff']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: []
    });

    // Override the provider for HomeService with the mock
    TestBed.overrideProvider(HomeService, { useValue: homeServiceMock });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    appComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should call DoStuff() when CallHomeService() is called', () => {
    // Call the CallHomeService() method of AppComponent
    appComponent.CallHomeService();

    // Expect that DoStuff() was called on the mock HomeService
    expect(homeService.DoStuff).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342781/angular-jasmine-spy-not-being-called) that if I use `providers` in the ts component it will override my Spy, but I still do not understand why my useValue is being override. It is not supposed only to provide the mock service in `providers` of `TestBed.configureTestingModule` with `useValue` to call the mock service? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're providing `HomeService` to your component via the component's `providers` array, the component is not getting the instance of `HomeService` created at the module level—the one you replaced with `useValue`—it's getting its own, separate instance.

If you remove `HomeService` from AppComponent's `providers` array, your original setup without `overrideProvider` should work.

[From the docs](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-services-in-modules-vs-components):

> Angular DI has a hierarchical injection system, which means that nested injectors can create their own service instances. Whenever Angular creates a new instance of a component that has providers specified in @Component(), it also creates a new child injector for that instance.

> Child modules and component injectors are independent of each other, and create their own separate instances of the provided services.

Comment: So he just needs to remove the providers array from AppComponent?

Comment: @JSmart523 yes, I updated my answer to explicitly state that.